# How to install qiskit in spyder editor?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am working in Anaconda using spyder editor.
Can anyone tell me how to install qiskit in spyder?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to [install](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html#installation) it using pip which should be already within anaconda. If not, check this [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/).

pip install qiskit